# one form store data in two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need a small help regarding a code in php & MYSQL and I'm new to this subject.. i have a single form.. and 
that form has two parts vehicle & driver information. when this form submitted this two different parts should store in  two different tables that two tables has related with "vehicle-No"..can u please give me a example coding to show me how to do it correctly. I'm Following the MVC Pattern

```
public function V_reg($v_no,$dl_no,$owner,$o_name,$o_nic,$i_date,$ex_date,$p_report,$nic,$s_name,$f_name,$initials,$dob,$stat) {

    $sql="INSERT INTO driverdetails (nic,sir_name,first_name,initials,dob,status )
            VALUES ('$nic','$s_name','$f_name','$initials','$dob','$stat')";

    $conn=new Connection();
    $results=$conn->query($sql);
    return $results;
    }
}
```

Above is how I send the data to a one table. The rest of captured data should go to the table called `vehicledetails`. I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: write one more insert query for another table insert

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and it has nothing to do with MVC pattern.

Comment: The example is on your code. Just copy the insert code, paste it and change the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store data by using single query then you have to use stored procedure otherwise find lastInsertId and then wrote another sql query and make lastInsertId as a foreign key.

public function V_reg ($v_no, $dl_no, $owner, $o_name, $o_nic, $i_date, $ex_date, $p_report, $nic, $s_name, $f_name, $initials, $dob, $stat) 
{

```
$sql="INSERT INTO driverdetails (nic,sir_name,first_name,initials,dob,status )
        VALUES ('$nic','$s_name','$f_name','$initials','$dob','$stat')";

$conn=new Connection();
$conn->query($sql);
$fk_key=$conn->lastInsertId();

$sql1="INSERT INTO vehicaldetails (driver_id,veh_no,dl_no )
        VALUES ('$fk_key','$v_no','$dl_no',)";

$results=$conn->query($sql1);

return $results;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it with coading examples ?